# ng-repeat filter not applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple code that pulls some data in intervals and prints into a table. I'd like to filter the table rows but any filters that I'm trying to apply are ignored. What am I missing? This is basically a plain copy from AngularJS [docs page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/filter/filter).

The only difference here seems to be that I'm using a controller and the example code does not.

Example [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3t760bAOAPr4E2XfESHO?p=preview).

HTML template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Last action</th>
      <th>Total time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input ng-model="search.count"></th>
      <th><input ng-model="search.last"></th>
      <th><input ng-model="search.time"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in adminCtrl.rows | filter:search ">
      <td>{{ row.count }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.last }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.time }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('admin', []);

  app.controller('AdminController', ['$interval', '$http', function($interval, $http){
    var admin = this;
    admin.rows = [];
    var timer = undefined;

    function updateRows() {
      $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) {
        admin.rows = data;
      });
    }

    admin.stopTimer = function() {
      if (angular.isDefined(timer)) {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
        timer = undefined;
      }
    };

    admin.startTimer = function(delay) {
      if (!angular.isDefined(delay)) {
        // Default interval 10 seconds.
        delay = 10000;
      }

      if (!angular.isDefined(timer)) {
        timer = $interval(updateRows, delay);
      }
    };

    admin.isTimerRunning = function() {
      return angular.isDefined(timer);
    }

    // Initialize rows.
    updateRows();

    // Start the interval timer.
    admin.startTimer();

  }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the filter is only apply in `array` where your data is an object. simply convert the data to array should work. if you happend to use `lo-dash`, that's a easy job to do :

```
function updateRows() {
    $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) {
        admin.rows = _.toArray(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know this is not the most productive comment, but: [FACEPALM](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/001/582/picard-facepalm.jpg)

Comment: @SiliconMind - FACEPALM for seeing AC w/o VU

Answer (score 0):

It's because your ng-repeat is repeating over an object and not an array, here is your adminCtrl.rows:

```
{"a":{"count":14,"last":"Lorem ipsum","time":45},"b":{"count":5,"last":"Some title","time":13}}
```

Make it an array:

```
[{"count":14,"last":"Lorem ipsum","time":45},{"count":5,"last":"Some title","time":13}}]
```

If you want to use filter over an object, you'll have to roll your own using a

```
.filter("MY_FILTER", function(){
    ...
});
```